# What strategy can I use to OCR Magic the Gathering corner text?

Tags: c, algorithm, go, ocr

I need to recognize the text in the bottom left corner on Magic the Gathering paper cards (last design). Here an example:

[image]

If the text is like this
[image: textocr]
I want to retrieve the following text:

```
198/280 U
M20 EN
```

(I don't need the card author name - Lake Hurwitz in this example)

What OCR library can I use? I've tried with Tesseract without any tuning but the results are not correct. Any advice or link to a project that already does this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with tesseract (3.04.01) by sanitizing your image a bit
like in below code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def prepro(zone, prefix):
    filename = 'stackmagic.png'
    oriimg = cv2.imread(filename)

    #keep the interesting part
    (a,b,c,d) = zone
    text_zone = oriimg[a:b, c:d]
    height, width, depth = text_zone.shape

    #resize it to be bigger (so less pixelized)
    H = 50
    imgScale = H/height
    newX,newY = text_zone.shape[1]*imgScale, text_zone.shape[0]*imgScale
    newimg = cv2.resize(text_zone,(int(newX),int(newY)))

    #binarize it
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(newimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, img = cv2.threshold(gray, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY);

    #erode it
    kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
    cv2.imwrite(prefix+'_ero.png', erosion)

    cv2.imshow("Show by CV2",erosion)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


prepro((16,27, 6,130), 'upzone')
prepro((27,36, 6,130), 'downzone')
```

from your [cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqxX.png)
you get

the upper part:

[image: upper part]

and the lower part:

[image]

and tesseract does seem to be able to extract

```
xx$ tesseract upzone_ero.png stdout
198/ 280 U

xx$ tesseract downzone_ero.png stdout
M20 ~ EN Duluu Hun-nu
```

Notice that we fail to extract Luke, but hopefully you were not interested in him/it :)

There are other tools but that'd be advertising stuff and be subjective..